# Ubuntu 16.04 deleted magento and need to restore it

Tags: magento2.3

My magento folder was deleted by mistake.

can we recover it? please help

Comment: Without backup, I think there is no chance to restore.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question belongs to https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but without backup there is no way to restore. If you are running Ubuntu on a virtual maschine you could try to restore a snapshot.

Comment: Please confirm my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Without a backup the only other possible option i can suggest would be is [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) this sometimes is able to recover recently deleted files.